# Excel VBA - Change Specific Conditional Formatting Rule

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to target a specific conditional formatting rule and change the "Applies To" Range. The rule is inside a `listobject`.

The rule has this expression:

```
=OR(CELL("row")=CELL("row",C13))
```

I don't know how to select a specific conditional formatting rule, perhaps by using an IF function by searching all rules in the listobject table?

```
 .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, xlEqual, "=OR(CELL("row")=CELL("row",C13))"
```

I could then use something like this to modify the range?

```
.FormatConditions(1).ModifyAppliesToRange Range(strRange)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to loop through the conditions to find the one(s) you want:

```
Set mySheet = ActiveSheet 
For Each fc In mySheet.UsedRange.FormatConditions
    If fc.Formula1 = "=OR(CELL(""row"")=CELL(""row"",C13))" then
        'Modify range here
    End if
Next fc
```

(this is untested)